# howto change html code in div through meteor sessions?

Tags: javascript, meteor

Is it possible to change html code in div containers through meteor sessions?

my html-code is

```
<template name="frame">
  <div class="container-fluid">
   {{html}}
  </div>
 </div>
</template>
```

my js-file looks like this

```
Template.frame.html = function() {
 if (Session.equals('current_frame', 1))
  return "Verwaltung";
 else if (Session.equals('current_frame', 2))
  return "Protokoll";
 else if (Session.equals('current_frame', 3))
  return "Informationen";
 else {
  return "";
 }
};
Template.menu.events({
 'tap, click .verwaltung':function(e,t) {
  Session.set('current_frame', 1);
 },
 'tap, click .protokoll':function(e,t){
  Session.set('current_frame', 2);
 },
 'tap, click .informationen':function(e,t){
  Session.set('current_frame', 3);
 }
});
```

i would like to change the {{html}} with different html-code depending on the session value.
is this possible? how can i achieve this?

i use meteor and bootstrap.

cheers!

Answer (score 1):

The only problem I see with your code is in `menu.events`. For multiple events, you need to specify which element will receive it **separatelly**:

```
Template.menu.events({
  'tap .vermaltung, click .verwaltung': function() {
    Session.set('current_frame', 1);
  }
}
```

Comment: well, from the meteor documentation it should be okay like that